# Select certificate at Windows base popup for .net core selenium c# application

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, ui-automation, autoit

How can i select security certificate in EDGE browser by automation tool.
Previously i was using AUTOIT tool and after selection of certificate i was using selenium library to automate web application.
After migration to .NET Core AutoIt library is no longer supported.
I am looking for some way to have possibility to select different certificates base on my needs.
AutoselectForUrls in Window Registry - it is not solution, because I want to select different certificates depends of test scenario.
Can anyone help? thank you in advance

My code looks like this:

```cs
private static readonly Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

public new IWebDriver Driver { get; set; }

public new string DownloadFolder { get; set; }

public string BaseUrl { get; set; }

public new void Start()
{
    DownloadFolder = @"C:\Users\user\Downloads";
    Driver = new EdgeDriver(@"C:\Users\Public\TrunkGit\edgedriver_win64 (4)\");
    string shortTimeoutFromAppSetings = BaseConfiguration.Builder["appSettings:shortTimeout"];
    //ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["shortTimeout"];
    double shortTimeout = Convert.ToDouble(shortTimeoutFromAppSetings);
    Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait=TimeSpan.FromSeconds(shortTimeout);
    Driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately we cannot answer your question unless we have more information. Can you [edit] your question to include a [repro]? We would need to see the current code that initializes EdgeDriver, and any attempts you have made at getting the desired behavior

Comment: The screenshot is a good visual, though. Keep the screenshot, but we need to see some code.

Comment: The code is a good start, but I don't see where the code navigates to any web site. I'm assuming it uses the `BaseUrl` property. Is this popup for an SSL certificate, or to authenticate a user with your web site?

Comment: yes popup for ssl. windows popup